# Трудности в отправке транзакции. Bitcoin. Provider API

Tags: java, sdk, key, bitcoin, transaction

Всем привет.

Сразу опережу, я в блокчейн технологиях и самом биткойне понимаю не много. Но по моим подсчетам, этих знаний должно вполне хватать чтобы пользоваться приватными и публичными ключами для генерирования транзакций.

История такова. Мне нужен был provider-API для Java, с помощью которого я бы смог отправлять транзакции и создавать адреса. Вездесущая bitcoinJ требует наличия собственной ноды с блокчейном для функционирования. Остальные провайдеры либо не имеют Java SDK, либо берут [свою комиссию](https://www.block.io/api/simple/curl), либо [требуют наличие своего коммерческого ресурса](http://api.blockchain.info). В итоге я пришел к [blockcypher api](https://github.com/blockcypher/java-client).

Прежде чем понять, как отправлять транзакции мне пришлось потратить 2 дня. Т.к. пример который указан на гитхабе в readme выбрасывал различные ошибки. Перекомбинировав различные варианты и потанцевав с бубном, методом перебора мне все же удалось вычислить комбинацию методов и подходов чтобы транзакция все-таки отправилась. Но кто мог знать что дальше меня ждет еще волны захватывающих эмоций.

В общем, на этот раз проблема совсем аномального(с моего уровня полета) генеза. После перехода аномальной точки бифуркации, доступ к адресу закрывается и я не могу перевести с него средства. Я вычислил что это происходит в такой комбинации:

1. **Сгенерировать 2 адреса**
2. **Пополнить 1 с помощью онлайн сервисов типа https://coinfaucet.eu/en/btc-testnet/**
3. **Перевести пару раз монеты с 1 на 2**
4. **Попытаться перевести обратно со 2 на 1(или на любой другой)** (на данном этапе все и обламывается)

Причем с 1 все еще можно будет переводить куда угодно монеты. 2 уже можно считать забракованым, с него никуда не вывести.
Не исключено что существуют еще комбинации в которых вылазит эта проблема. Но пока что я выявил только такую закономерность.
Есть еще один момент. Если после этого создать еще 3 адрес и пополнить его извне. То с 3 тоже нельзя будет отправить на 1. Все остальные комбинации возможны. Т.е. 3->2, 1->3. Надеюсь хотя-бы немного понятно выразился.
Проблема не в недостатке средств! Я всегда дожидаюсь пока будет хотя бы одно подтверждение сети!

Сама ошибка выкидывается последним методом в приведенном ниже коде. Выглядит вот так:

```
BlockCypherException{message=Bad Request, status=400, blockCypherError=[Error{error='Error reading signatures and pubkeys: Counts of public keys and signatures are not equal..'}], exception=null}
```

А вот пример транзакций, которые ее вызвают:

```
{"tx":{"hash":"3930029653f65375db2ef227be24639b8d8c33272136386c239b3b723599b700","block_height":-1,"addresses":["mm1UEmcppHf1dhLqVXoUwpce7whw4cHCS9","myn4YcaU1h4VURSVVZsSNoYUho9GCcqmRU"],"total":21453193,"fees":23600,"relayed_by":"78.128.150.96","received":"2018-09-20T21:32:40.603523199Z","ver":1,"vin_sz":3,"vout_sz":1,"confirmations":0,"preference":"high","double_spend":false,"inputs":[{"prev_hash":"a30cd76ad10b500a6dc9a17ad118da9fc80d4aa02dcba64fd0018ecf5b37ba2d","output_index":0,"output_value":76931,"addresses":["mm1UEmcppHf1dhLqVXoUwpce7whw4cHCS9"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"},{"prev_hash":"c862edbfb9bd64dd16a90a6d575d35affc8e7eafa77d1492a2722742f56e3f21","output_index":0,"output_value":7693,"addresses":["mm1UEmcppHf1dhLqVXoUwpce7whw4cHCS9"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"},{"prev_hash":"e5b44f7452d76d3a1cf14b36b204c68a7b311ef8824c7fc1e095d5f3296103d0","output_index":0,"output_value":21392169,"addresses":["mm1UEmcppHf1dhLqVXoUwpce7whw4cHCS9"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}],"outputs":[{"value":21453193,"script":"76a914c84db8bd4b66fbffaf91c5ca11dc3f398d603b6d88ac","addresses":["myn4YcaU1h4VURSVVZsSNoYUho9GCcqmRU"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}]},"tosign":["493da515f2c84fceb56de759940eeb598f9ba304e6a2651534a838f796d930ff","f13cb2beca8a470aee60c6f27f64eadc00addde04df55771668f0e12409e3058","88ea0fc5f68ffa57c4c4479bf3565d64f49b0e5d75fa645b5f71c30d60374351"],"signatures":["3045022100b5652ba3310d3fafde713ab9cd9628c9d617e2e969f9687b6938bdb07e3a99a3022064facf1853da51e7f426bfef5ea8f50fb301de6efc6796e43915078ff9ce987a","304502210095336bcd28c1f08b31f6e25bfc77421f3ec7556089626ee09720ed44e51e6a8302201adaa05e32d561955ec0c0193daaa4ff246cdd4207b2ca8d09781a73af6ecc21","30440220086c4c9833173d68179e2da9c79f1c92f9cff9717ea3caf5014d6f191999bb30022058f6162ce01227611143e5632f8e077013546d73d735daed0202df5762d4e1bc"],"pubkeys":["0388e410aa94114b5a0fb683be1e15ef7e8f6ac4a3555beac22f4f8d2575dde60e"]}

{"tx":{"hash":"7befea4f60cfbc50597a03346add775bf7b4bb0f5f428a9582b32ce79da474ed","block_height":-1,"addresses":["msggp35jUPYubFU2zPm8YHYDunat7c244g","mogaQxPWuaQH9mB85Z5eGeL5ABrcX2PYqf"],"total":45212,"fees":30600,"relayed_by":"78.128.150.96","received":"2018-09-20T23:19:11.202405866Z","ver":1,"vin_sz":4,"vout_sz":2,"confirmations":0,"preference":"high","double_spend":false,"inputs":[{"prev_hash":"c806ed8b26bbebbd293f792f85d6534785b0bac3a7103d4c1a9460ef740d7252","output_index":0,"output_value":5858,"addresses":["msggp35jUPYubFU2zPm8YHYDunat7c244g"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"},{"prev_hash":"90a140afa6941819791232423e48ac29c5f4bb6654e0daba5a548e9f8789ac50","output_index":0,"output_value":7000,"addresses":["msggp35jUPYubFU2zPm8YHYDunat7c244g"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"},{"prev_hash":"957c81ee26c5ca653768050d8ebaed886e2ffb48400ca80ccdb1fe4badd16ef3","output_index":0,"output_value":7000,"addresses":["msggp35jUPYubFU2zPm8YHYDunat7c244g"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"},{"prev_hash":"6e6a20dce45febf93cd5b13579d98138ab0918de9c1961b8c9c6505d02b0221d","output_index":0,"output_value":55954,"addresses":["msggp35jUPYubFU2zPm8YHYDunat7c244g"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}],"outputs":[{"value":7000,"script":"76a9145992e68a2ac35feffbee743e092cec95cc7b9f3288ac","addresses":["mogaQxPWuaQH9mB85Z5eGeL5ABrcX2PYqf"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"},{"value":38212,"script":"76a9148578be922d6fc2e391ac668203dcedf44dd32b6c88ac","addresses":["msggp35jUPYubFU2zPm8YHYDunat7c244g"],"script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"}]},"tosign":["9191af28a70c531aaf6f9f6eb5f44077e4d26ecfcd7fd0c6d544c352dd9ade9e","4905f011ac0449cf56cc927d07ea7e233f3f9fa96d720de0f70dae774676b151","ed20429e349915b3fec3a443d0e4ee962d6ff98639581e5541cfa555ae6fc936","cf906927e62ce445529601e496c826b0332bf156effe2c39e7a8b3d80d0c3e92"],"signatures":["30440220541d9227b0eb4d8bae3dc3c1e6c4e0868debe244e03d9ab3ebb6a4b1b6ece90c0220326bfdb53f6800f97c5071a99f1dee0915e01d2814699f15e8d3c547a5cbe75a","30440220797a533a1ce452edaa8e24634e4a3024124205d903cb687e9dcec51291dec320022011e8083108319d6856674e869d62197d837ece0f4bc4a4cdff7aa4c8ccb17fc1","3044022017f3429f7ccc4fb3d137e04b94a47e2ba4d19f05d017514f29ae687de65b996402202e7a58d809c222c9d01a1473650af9e01bf84bf7ca62cf101277d31bbac5a1be","3044022056848052dc3237d41abf6cb3d716bf7021a30f3346db11b301bb7c6b27339a70022072790eaebf49a63c25406103779ead18de66f70a4d9f52a060c5d2419e308774"],"pubkeys":["02fb6e3502b464dd5335fb48113bc9b2cee2a36a2e6edfff9c94e8ac8225541f5e"]}
```

Вот мой, полу-рабочий, добытый кровью и потом код отправки транзакции:

```
private static Transaction sendBtc(String from, String to, String privateKey, String pubKey, long value) throws Exception {
        IntermediaryTransaction unsignedTX = null;
        long satoshi = value;

        unsignedTX = context.getTransactionService().
                newTransaction(
                        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(from)),
                        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(to)), satoshi);

        unsignedTX.addPubKeys(pubKey);

        SignUtils.signWithHexKeyNoPubKey(unsignedTX, privateKey);

        return context.getTransactionService().sendTransaction(unsignedTX);
    }
```

Причем, прошу заметить, я использую метод signWithHexKey**NoPubKey**, но при этом добавляю публичный ключ к транзакции **unsignedTX.addPubKeys(pubKey);**. Именно данная комбинация "работает". Остальные комбинации с signWithHexKey**WithPubKey** и т.д. не работают вообще!

Было бы конечно хорошо разобраться в чем проблема и решить ее. **Но я с радостью приму и другие варианты. Может вы знаете лучшее решение для работы с BTC адресами в Java, без загрузки огромного блокчейна на машину.**

Очень буду признателен если вы поможете. Сам я уже не вижу никаких исходов. Полный тупик. Спасибо.

Comment: Я не думаю, что вы здесь найдете человека, который работал с BlockCypher и сможет вам помочь. Судя по гитхабу проект забросили 3 года назад, а за это время было много улучшений в протоколе биткоина.  Невозможно создать транзакцию имея на руках только адрес. Посмотрите лучше, как самому создать транзакцию имея UTXO (unspent transaction output) и приватный ключ. Такую транзакцию можно создать полностью офлайн. Получить UTXO можно используя протокол электрум (вам нужно найти рабочий сервер) при помощи метода `blockchain.scripthash.listunspent`. А потом отправить `blockchain.transaction.broadcast`

Comment: Вот описание протокола: https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html